# Typeguard against null[]

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeguards

I am working with some autogenerated types from graphQL-data and need a way to make a typeguard against null, undefined and null[] to narrow types.

So far the I got this:

```
export default function validData<T>(
  condition: T
): asserts condition is Exclude<T, null | undefined | null[]> {
  if (
    condition === null ||
    condition === undefined ||
    (Array.isArray(condition) && typeof condition[0] === null)
  ) {
    throw new Error(
      `missing data: ${condition} returned null, null[] or undefined`
    );
  }
}
```

And then I simply use the function like this:

```
validData(menuDataToNarrow):
```

The function is working against null and undefined, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to catch and throw errors if the data contains an empty array? The above code was my best (non-working) attempt so far.
The types are narrowed as expected when it comes to null and undefined, but I still get:

```
XXX is not assignable to type null[]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: I came up with this finished guard that works:

```
export default function validData<T>(
  condition: T
): asserts condition is Exclude<T, null | undefined | null[]> {
  if (
    condition === null ||
    condition === undefined ||
    (Array.isArray(condition) && condition.every((x) => x === null))
  ) {
    throw new Error(
      `missing data: ${condition} returned null, null[] or undefined`
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Empty array check is is just `Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0` - is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null[]` Would be an array with nulls. You can check that with [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
I think you are looking for 'an empty array' which is `[]` an array with length 0 or `Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0` as @VLAZ suggested in the comments

<sup>Edit based on your comment:</sup>
Be careful to correctly check for null and/or undefined in your code. I've tried defining an empty array but it does not seem trivial in TS

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I was after and sorry for my bad wording: of course I meant an array of nulls (null[]).
I accepted your answer, as it solved my question :-)

Comment: Good because I couldn't really find an easy solution for an empty array